# How can I send a struct of arrays into a function when using the String object?

Tags: c++

I'm learning to code c++ and I've come to this problem:
I have this `struct`:

```
struct storeData
{
  string name;
  string username;
  string fav_food;
  string fav_color;

}data[30];
```

And I need to check if two usernames are equal so I made this statement:

```
  for(i=0;i<c;i++){

          if(data[c].username.compare(data[i].username)==0){
            cout<<"Username already taken"<<endl;
          }
  }
```

And it works well, the problem that I have is that I'm required to make a function let's call it: `isTaken` that returns the error message, so I can use it whenever I need to for example delete a username so I don't have to copy/paste the code again.
So I began looking for an answer for that, many forums present a way to send the whole struct like this:

`void isTaken(struct storeData *data)`

which I understand but because I'm using `string` is not working, so I guess it's because string is an object? I'm using the library `<string>` I'm sorry if I'm not being that clear at the moment, I'm looking for a way to use `isTaken(data[c].user);` but I don't know how to declare the function, I think is also because `string` is not the same as C `string` but I'm not really sure I've been looking for a solution and could not find it.
I tried: `void isTaken(struct storeData *data)` but I got an error saying that I can't convert `std::string to basic_string` which makes sense if I'm correct about `string` I tried converting string into c string but could not get anywhere. I'm open to suggestions/corrections because I want to improve my code, also I could not find the answer here, so If someone's got a link to a problem like this please let me know.
Thank you so much for you time, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean an array of structs instead of a struct of arrays?
In the example you are giving I see only an array of structs each of which has multiple string objects in it. You see, a `string` is a class coming from `std` and I wouldn't call it an array. If you want to know how to pass an array to a function, you should read about it (I'm sure you can find such a question in SO). If you want to have an array within your struct, then the struct will take care of the memory of the array, but you should definitely read about constructors.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. I mixed up languages, I'll give it a read thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You got an error because you are passing an string argument to a function which requires struct pointer

```cpp
void isTaken(struct storeData *data);
...
isTaken(data[c].user);
```

but what you actually need is to have a function which takes an array of your users, its size and username you want to check

```cpp
bool IsUsernameTaken(struct storeData data[], int dataSize, const string &username){
    for(int i = 0; i<dataSize; i++){
        if(username == data[i].username)
            return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: I see, I never looked at it that way. how can I call that function into main()? 
```IsUsernameTaken()```?

Comment: Lets look at the function header ```bool IsUsernameTaken(struct storeData data[], int dataSize, const string &username)```. It requires 3 arguments, array of your data, size of array and username you want to check. So if you want to call it, you have to supply these three arguments. ```IsUsernameTaken(data,40,"your name")```

Answer (score 0):

A C string looks like this

```
data
```

A C++ string usually looks like this

```
size
capacity
ptr
 | 
 v
data
```

or if using short string optimization and the string is short enough

```
size
data
data
```

all are zero terminated.

Making a shallow copy a C string only cost the copy of the pointer to it. Where a copy of a might cost just copying the 3 members and possible an allocation of data, which is not ideal, therefor most C++ functions use a reference to a string making the cost equivalent to the C string.

*All code is untested.*

```
bool Find(const std::string& target);
```

Making a deep copy of a C string would also cost an allocation.

In C++ you have many options to do a search, for your struct it could look like this. In case your member variables are private you must use an access function

```
auto found = std::find(std::begin(data), std::begin(data)+c, [&target](const storeData& auser) { return auser.GetName() == target });
return (found != std::begin(data)+c);
```

The first two parameters are the range that is search, not including the 2nd. A lambda is used to check the name, a free function with the right declaration would also do.

```
std::string& GetName() { return name; }
```

The higher C++ protection schemes would advice adding 2 consts to that in case you don't need to change name.

```
const std::string& GetName() const { return name; }
```

Meaning the returned string cant be changed and the 2nd says it wont change anything in your class. This const version would be required as I used a `const storeData& auser` in the lambda to satisfy the constness of the struct.

Comment: Such an elegant answer, I'll give it a try and write you back. Thanks a lot for your time!